How to suspend nx auto rebuild?
We use the @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server executor to build and run our TypeScript application. NX keeps a watch on the sources, so whenever anything changes, it will automatically launch a rebuild, which is very convenient. Basically.
The good: The initial compilation takes quite some time. For our current project, easily a few minutes. Subsequent rebuilds are typically much faster, thanks to NX caching partial results.
The bad: NX is somewhat overzealous. It will rebuild as soon as something has changed. More often than not, my changes are not restricted to a single file, though, and I would rather tell NX to launch its rebuild only after I have also edited the second and the third file.
Is there any way to suspend NX's rebuilding (without entirely stopping the process!), or bring it in a mode where it is waiting for my command to actually trigger the rebuild? Preferrably without changing the NX config to the extent that it disables the auto-rebuild-upon-file-change for all the other developers in the project who like it the way it is?
